# Boundedness of real part of analytic function on the boundary implies boundedness in the disk

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let f be analytic in an open neigbourhood containing the closed ball $\overline{B}(0,R)$ and $f(0)=0$.  If $Re(f(z)) \leq M $ on $\partial{B}(0,R)$ then $Re(f(z)) \leq M$ in $\overline{B}(0,R)$. I'm not sure how to tackle this, any proofs?

Comment: Can you use maximum modulus principle for harmonic functions?

Comment: I was originally looking for a proof that doesn't involve harmonic functions, but the result is really straightforward with what you suggested since the real part of an analytic function is harmonic. Thanks!

Comment: Just apply MMP to $e^{f}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That works too since $|e^{f(z)}|=e^{Re(f(z))}$ . Thanks!